# Diablo III Lazarus's Grimoire Missing Bug

Tags: diablo-iii

> A Page from Lazarus's Grimoire is dropped after witnessing the
>   beheading of Queen Asylla in The Cursed Hold.

Source...

http://diablo.gamepedia.com/A_Page_from_Lazarus%27s_Grimoire

The problem is that I've done this twice and it doesn't appear. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is that specific page already in your found pages/booklist? Pages only drop once per character (over all difficulties together)

Comment: It's not highlighted on the relevant achievement hence why I inquired about it not dropping.

Comment: Have you tried to get this page with another char yet?

Comment: I've had issues in the past with these achievements not being awarded. The only way to fix it is to get the page with a different character. I'm not sure about this achievement in particular, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journal entries are a 100% drop from the relevant game container or interaction.

If a bug has prevented one from dropping for your character, an alternative would be to retrieve the entry on another character. While journal entries are unlocked per character, the achievement is tracked across all characters.